# how to find array with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have an array that depending of my input, will return different name for a particular node. For example below I the name of the key node is `n1:ModemProduct1207` but it could be also `n1:ModemProduct1308`.

I was wondering is there is a way to have something like this:

```
$array ['n1:ModemProducts'] ['n1:ModemProduct'. (regex here like"n1:ModemProduct[\d0-9]{4}+")];
$modemProducts = $array ['n1:ModemProducts'] ['n1:ModemProduct1207'];
```

I tried couple of options but could not get it to work.

Comment: Show us what you've tried!

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/preg_grep http://php.net/array_keys

Comment: You should add to your question: Sample array structure (input) desired result (output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little function for one-dimensional array:

```
function filterProducts($array, $pattern){
  $result = array();
  foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if (preg_match($pattern, $key)){
      $result[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
$results = filterProducts($array['n1:ModemProducts'], '/n1:ModemProduct[\d]{4}/');
```

Comment: thank you Jaroslav, thank worked like a charme.

Answer (score 0):

`$array = array('Armenia', 'America', 'Algeria', 'India', 'Brazil', 'Croatia', 'Denmark');`

$fl_array = preg_grep('/^A.*/', $array);

print_r($fl_array);

for referance you can see . http://ask.amoeba.co.in/php-search-in-an-array-for-values-matching-a-pattern-regex-wildcard/

I am Trying to solve your problam

Hope this Help

Thanks
Anand

Comment: hes looking to match a *key* with a regex, not values.